Why graphql apollo-client request's has different response timeout in local and cloud
I have a nestjs application which uses graphql apollo-client data fetching, using nginx for load-balancing.
I have encountered 2 different timeout while connecting to the local and cloud backend.

when connected with cloud i was getting a timeout after 30seconds but not exactly 30 seconds.eg: 30.5S
but when local backend is connected the timeout was exactly at 1 minute or 60seconds.

timeout when connected with local
timeout when connected with cloud
Observation

The timeout in local was because of the nginx proxy_read_timeout & proxy_write_timeout and i fixed handled by increasing it for more than 60 seconds.
but in cloud with the same nginx.conf i was getting timeout around 30S . I am not getting where is the fix needed.

I am hosted in GCP with GKE
